# Extracting Values from a String

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract values from a string, I have tried to get `re.match` working but have not had any luck. The string is:

```
'/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'
```

I have tried:

```
 map(int,re.search("Value\s*=\s*").group(1))
```

and also:

```
'/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'.split(' = ')
```

I am not sure what else to add or do. I want to retrieve the attributes `'Value, Max, Step'` and their values. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that *particular* string, the following parses it into a dictionary:

```
s = '/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'
d = {}
for pair in [val.split('=') for val in s.split('\r\n')[1:-1]]:
    d[pair[0]] = int(pair[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = '/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'
>>> bits = s.split('\r\n')
>>> val, max_val, step = [int(bits[i].partition(' = ')[2]) for i in [1, 3, 4]]
>>> val
1800
>>> max_val
3600
>>> step
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'
data = {}

for l in s.split('\r\n'):
     if " = " in l:
             k,v = l.split(" = ")
             data[k] = int(v)

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use regexp, but I think you can simply split it by `\r\n` and then use values with `=`.

Something like:

```
s = '/opt/ad/bin$ ./ptzflip\r\nValue = 1800\r\nMin = 0\r\nMax = 3600\r\nStep = 1\r\n'
dct = {}
arr = [ss for ss in s.split('\r\n') if '=' in ss]
for e in arr:
    k, v = e.split(' = ')
    dct[k] = v
print dct
```