# How do i take out values from a string? Python

Tags: python, string

My task is to create an offset factor which is based on an eight character key which is calculated earlier in the program. firstly each of the characters in the eight character key need to be converted into equivalent ascii numbers, then added together, then dividing that result by 8 and then rounding down to a whole number. finally, 32 needs to be subtracted from that value.

this is my code before the offset factor:

```
def EncryptCode():
    userFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n")
    with open (userFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
        encrypt = encrypt_file.read()
    print ("Code that will be encrypted:")
    printMessage(encrypt)
    eightNumKey = (chr(random.randint(33,126)) for _ in range(8))
    print('\nEight-Character Key:', "".join(eightNumKey))
```

This is how I tried to implement the offset factor into the program:

```
def EncryptCode():
    userFileLoad = input("Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':\n")
    with open (userFileLoad,mode="r",encoding="utf=8") as encrypt_file:
        encrypt = encrypt_file.read()
    print ("Code that will be encrypted:")
    printMessage(encrypt)
    offsetFactor = 0
    eightNumKey = (chr(random.randint(33,126)) for _ in range(8))
    print('\nEight-Character Key:', "".join(eightNumKey))
    offsetFactor = offsetFactor + ord(eightNumKey)  #I need help with this bit
    offsetFactor = offsetFactor / 8
    offsetFactor = math.floor(offsetFactor)
    offsetFactor = offsetFactor - 32
    text = encrypt.split()
    print("The offset Factor is:",offsetFactor)
```

this is what my output shows:

```
This program has three choices.

1. Encrypt a message.

2. Decrypt the message.

3. Exit the program.


Make your choice: 1
Name the file and directory you want to load with the ending '.txt':
Sample.txt
Code that will be encrypted:


Somewhere in la Mancha, in a place whose name I do not care to remember, a gentleman lived not long ago, one of those who has a lance and ancient shield on a shelf and keeps a skinny nag and a greyhound for racing.

Eight-Character Key: txJ#K_P`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Computer Science\Course Work\Controlled assessment\Controlled Assessment.py", line 54, in <module>
showMenu()
  File "N:\Computer Science\Course Work\Controlled assessment\Controlled Assessment.py", line 38, in showMenu
    EncryptCode()
  File "N:\Computer Science\Course Work\Controlled assessment\Controlled Assessment.py", line 26, in EncryptCode
    offsetFactor = offsetFactor + ord(eightNumKey)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but generator found
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. eightNumKey is a sequence of characters, which you obviously know because you've previously used `join` on it. What are you expecting `ord()` to do with that sequence? Also, I don't understand why you construct the sequence by calling `chr()` on an int, then immediately want to call `ord()` on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting Values from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093812/extracting-values-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JaimeCockburn has the answer to your question.  I wanted to show how you might refactor your code using `xrange` and `random.sample` and avoid converting numbers to strings then back to numbers.

```
>>> 
>>> ints = xrange(33, 127)
>>> key = random.sample(ints, 8)
>>> key
[78, 75, 77, 73, 94, 60, 44, 67]
>>> offset = sum(key)
>>> offset
568
>>> key = ''.join(map(chr, key))
>>> key
'NKMI^<,C'
```

`ints` can be reused.

```
>>> 
>>> key = random.sample(ints, 8)
>>> key
[90, 114, 93, 112, 40, 43, 95, 79]
>>> offset = sum(key)
>>> offset
666
>>> key = ''.join(map(chr, key))
>>> key
'Zr]p(+_O'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
eightNumKey = (chr(random.randint(33,126)) for _ in range(8))
```

The `(a for x in y)` syntax creates a generator.  A generator is something that can be iterated, but creates each item of the iteration as it goes.  The actual items are not created at that point, but at the point they are accessed.

You then iterate all the items in the generator when you print them out:

```
print('\nEight-Character Key:', "".join(eightNumKey))
```

After this line, the generator is empty, and you can never get the items back again.

Finally, you are trying to get the ordinal value of that generator, which doesn't make any sense:

```
offsetFactor = offsetFactor + ord(eightNumKey)  # eightNumKey is a generator
```

---

**Solution**

You actually want something more like this:

```
# Create a list, not a generator
eightNumKey = [chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for _ in range(8)]
# Iterate the list to print them out
print('\nEight-Character Key:', "".join(eightNumKey))
# Iterate the list again to sum the ordinal values
offsetFactor = sum(ord(c) for c in eightNumKey)
...
```

---

*Update:*
As a commenter mentions, you are effectively doing `ord(chr(random_number))`, which is somewhat redundant, as the end result is just `random_number` again.  You could just store the integer values in the list, and convert them to characters when you print them out, saving converting them back and forward.

Comment: You might want to demonstrate that ```ord(chr(n))``` equals ```n```.

Answer (score 0):

Wanna try this:

```
offset_factor = 0
    for i in range(0, 8):
        offset_factor = offset_factor + ord(key[i])
    offset_factor = offset_factor // 8 - 32
```